# Why does my optimised IL store the same value in the save variable twice?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-optimization, cil

The source code is a for loop as follows:

```
public class ForLoop
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i = i++)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have compiled it with optimisations turned on (`csc /o+ ForLoop.cs`), but the IL has a `dup`, followed by two `stloc.1` and a `ldloc.1`.

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       22 (0x16)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init (int32 V_0,
           int32 V_1)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0001:  stloc.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0003:  stloc.1
  IL_0004:  br.s       IL_0010
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0008:  add
  IL_0009:  stloc.0
  IL_000a:  ldloc.1
  IL_000b:  dup
  IL_000c:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000d:  add
  IL_000e:  stloc.1
  IL_000f:  stloc.1
  IL_0010:  ldloc.1
  IL_0011:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0013:  blt.s      IL_0006
  IL_0015:  ret
} // end of method ForLoop::Main
```

The instructions as `IL_000b` duplicate the the `i` variable in my for loop.  Then it adds 1 to it, stores the result, so what's left on the stack is my original value of `i`, pre-add.  Then, it stores it *again*, and loads it again.

This doesn't feel optimal or even correct.

So why is it doing it?

Comment: What do you suppose should it do otherwise with your `i = i++` instruction?  Why not just put `++i`?

Comment: @nvoigt That's it!  Thank you.  It's just a typo on my part.  If you want to stick it as the answer then I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Just mark Justin's, it's great and he took the time to actually write a full-blown answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand that `i++` is actually three operations:

1. Get the value of `i`
2. Add one to the value and store it.
3. Push the new value back into `i`.

Second of all, your code is wrong. Your loop has `i = i++` (rather than the usual simple `i++`) which is why you're seeing the extra two assignments.

You're doing the three steps mentioned about plus storing the result of `i++` and then pushing it back into `i`.

Comment: Yup, t'was a typo on my part.  I would have expected (with no evidence to support this) that the optimiser would have spotted this stupidity on my part on optimised it away.

Comment: @BanksySan take a look at the machine code, maybe the JIT optimized it away.